# How to solve axios post request problem that does not show on get request on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I used axios to do some post request ,
in this code I posted a new username but after posting it I cant get my posted name from api how can I solve this problem to see my posted request

```
const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.data)
            setData(res.data)
        })
    }, [])
    let getData = () => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.data)
            setData(res.data)
        })
    }
    let postData = () => {
        axios
            .post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
                name: 'test',
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
        getData()
    }
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <button onClick={postData}>post data</button>
            <button onClick={getData}>get data</button>

            {data.map((data, key) => (
                <p key={key}> {data.name} </p>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want to update your state locally upon post; of course you'd need a custom backend which takes your post input and updates the data set returned upon a get request, the jsonplaceholder does not achieve that. See an example and some comments on your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-browser-t1wp5?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Sorry, minus why?

Answer (score 0):

you are not waiting on the response of the `POST` before doing the `GET`, move the `getData` into the `then` callback of the `POST` request -

```
let postData = () => {
        axios
            .post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
                name: 'test',
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                getData()
            })
        
    }
```

though only do this if you are sure that the data is available immediately for the `GET` i.e. you are not queuing writes to the database or anything.

Though as a side note, if you using the 'jsonplaceholder' dummy API, surely it's not going to update anyway? It's going to return the same response everytime?

Looks like from their docs, on a POST request, you should be able to get the response like -

```
let postData = () => {
        axios
            .post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
                name: 'test',
            })
            .then((res) => {
               setData(res.data)
            });        
    }
```

(no need for the `GET` request)

Comment: i did this but still i cant get my posted name . i saw some trainings that they're posted the name and got that on ui with jsonplaceholder

Comment: in console i can see that the request is sending as same as the name that is posting but on get request i cant see that post request

Comment: its a dummy API, what makes you think that the GET request will return you your updated data? From their docs - "Important: resource will not be really updated on the server but it will be faked as if."

Comment: i just saw from a video and i did the same GET/POST . i got this error `response.json is not a function`

Comment: if my code is right its ok if i can not get the posted request  . i just think that the problem is my code because of the training video

Comment: of course, you're using `axios`, not `fetch`, updated my answer